# How to sync items with quanty managing buttons when removing items from cart?

Tags: reactjs

When I try to remove items from cart, the item is removed from the cart but the quanity buttons is not removed with that item, and it is asigned to the next item. How to link these buttons with the product item, and how to redefine the remove function in the code.

Trying to remove items from the cart, but the quanty buttons - 1 + is removed along with the item, and it is assigned to the next item in the cart

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Cart from "./Cart";

function App() {
  const [prdts, setPrdts] = useState([]);

  const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "iPhone 9",
      description: "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
      price: 549,
      discountPercentage: 12.96,
      rating: 4.69,
      stock: 94,
      brand: "Apple",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/1.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/2.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/3.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/4.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "iPhone X",
      description:
        "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
      price: 899,
      discountPercentage: 17.94,
      rating: 4.44,
      stock: 34,
      brand: "Apple",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/1.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/2.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/3.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Samsung Universe 9",
      description:
        "Samsung's new variant which goes beyond Galaxy to the Universe",
      price: 1249,
      discountPercentage: 15.46,
      rating: 4.09,
      stock: 36,
      brand: "Samsung",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/3/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: ["https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/3/1.jpg"],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "OPPOF19",
      description: "OPPO F19 is officially announced on April 2021.",
      price: 280,
      discountPercentage: 17.91,
      rating: 4.3,
      stock: 123,
      brand: "OPPO",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/1.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/2.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/3.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/4.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/thumbnail.jpg",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "Huawei P30",
      description:
        "Huawei’s re-badged P30 Pro New Edition was officially unveiled yesterday in Germany and now the device has made its way to the UK.",
      price: 499,
      discountPercentage: 10.58,
      rating: 4.09,
      stock: 32,
      brand: "Huawei",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/1.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/2.jpg",
        "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/3.jpg",
      ],
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    setPrdts(products);
  }, []);

  const remove = (removeItem) => {
    setPrdts(prdts.filter((item) => item.id != removeItem.id));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Cart prdts={prdts} remove={remove} />
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

function Cart({ prdts, remove }) {
  return (
    <table className="table table-success">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" colSpan={5}>
            Cart
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {prdts.map((product, index) => {
          return <Card product={product} key={index} remove={remove} />;
        })}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot className="sticky-bottom">
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={2}>SUBTOTAL:</td>
          <td colSpan={2}>$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={2}>SHIPPING</td>
          <td colSpan={2}>FREE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={2}>TOTAL</td>
          <td colSpan={2}>$</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Card({ product, remove }) {
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    qty > 1 && setQty((qty) => qty - 1);
  };

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    if (product.stock - qty > 0) {
      setQty((qty) => qty + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div className="card mb-3" style={{ maxWidth: "540px" }}>
          <div className="row g-0">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <img
                src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300
            "
                className="img-fluid rounded-start"
                alt="..."
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{product.title}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">{product.description}</p>
                <p className="card-text">
                  <small className="text-body-secondary">
                    Ratings: {product.rating}
                  </small>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button> {qty}
        <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>${qty * product.price}.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            remove(product);
          }}
        >
          Remove
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: This is mostly a guess, but `key={index}` looks suspicious.  Using the index as a key is possible, but for anything but the simplest of lists is not recommended.  What happens if you use an identifier in the data?  For example: `key={product.id}`

Comment: @David, here {prdts.map((product,) => {
          return <Card product={product} key={product.id} remove={remove} />;
        })}, right?

Comment: Did it make a difference?

Comment: worked! :) thanks @David. Could you explain what happened there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a subtle thing, but notice the `key` value here:

```
<Card product={product} key={index} remove={remove} />
```

In a great many cases, all one often does in a `.map()` over an array in JSX is simply display output.  A bulleted list of values, for example.  And so in a great many cases we find ourselves with no meaningful key and we just use the iteration index so we don't get a warning.

This approach is not recommended though, and the reason why is because of what you've discovered.  The `key` means something to React.  React uses it to understand the structure of that collection of elements/components and maintain/optimize their display.

In this case it appears that React is effectively re-using the components based on the index in the array.  So when you delete one part-way through the array, the rest of them now have a *new* `key` value because their index changed.  What *was* "component 3" is now "component 2" in that rendered list.  And it has all of the state that "component 2" had before the re-render.

Overall, the simplified lesson here is to use a meaningful `key` when rendering lists.  The positional index is fine for lists which don't do anything meaningful and don't change in any way.  But for anything remotely complex as you have here, a meaningful identifier for that data record is better than a positional index:

```
<Card product={product} key={product.id} remove={remove} />
```

Comment: Yes , I got that, If the key is unique rather than index as in my case, the whole component is removed specific of that key other wise it will begin from index zero.

Comment: Do have suggestions for react related textbook or something to better understand of react

Comment: @JeevaM: I do not.  My own learning was looking for tutorials on Google and contributing to projects at my job.

Comment: Got your points @David